# Library or framework to test a Java class structure

Tags: java, testing, reflection, assert

I have this ... set of classes that I use to see if a created class matches a given structure. What I'm doing is to read a properties file and then compare it with a class.

ie.

```
className: demo.HelloWorld
classFile: demo/HelloWorld.class
methods:   public static main(java/lang.String[]) : void 
attributes: name : java.lang.String
```

And so on.

Before I continue working on something like this, I would like to know if anyone knows of a library or framework to do the same.

Comment: I have to seriously wonder why you would do this. This seems like massive violation of DRY. I would understand if it was rule based (like all classes that implement this interface should be named like).

Comment: @Adam: For testing of course. I want to test if a class file ( a .class file ) contains the class, methods, attributes etc. it says it does. Yeah, testing is basically DO Repeat Yourself :)

Comment: I must be missing something. So you envision someone writing these property files along with the Java classes? Why not just write regular unit tests. For testing I always try to go for the most bang-for-your-buck and the level of contract testing you are doing doesn't seem worth it. Particularly since real unit tests will refactor and show compile time errors if you rename the method/attribute. If you just trying to do naming consistency see my answer.

Comment: How can a class say it contains methods or attributes that it really doesn't contain?

Answer (score 1):

To do this well, you'd need to have a Java parser that was able to parse the "structures" (Java fragments) and likely able to look up the types involved.  (You could likely do this badly with some scripting langauge, but it would be extremely fragile and prone to producing false negatives, which would eat the very time you hope this tool might save you).

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html) is a framework that has these capabilities.  DMS is designed to enable one to build arbitrary custom tools for analyzing or transforming source code.
DMS provides parsers (which one is defined by the chosen front end), AST builders, symbol table construction for languages such a C, C++, Java and COBOL, tools for inspecting trees both procedurally and using surface syntax patterns, which allow to you to directly express fragments of code (as determined by the front end parse) for code generation or pattern matching purposes.

For the task you want to do, you'd have DMS parse the software of interest, and do name and type resolution (build up the symbol tables).  Then you would want to use DMS's pattern parser to read your "specification file" as a set of method signatures, etc, and using the name resolver to locate/lookup identifiers (e.g, "demo.Helloworld), find the corresponding classes, and then match the parsed pattern against the method signatures.  And mismatches would report an inconsistency, which is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: I guess I could build a small DSL ( actually this is what my .properties file is ) I'm not sure if using a a tool like DMS would be an overkill or not. I'll find out

Comment: @OscarRyz: Just a DSL for your specification isn't enough. Without the ability to *really* parse Java and do name/type resolution, I don't think you'll be able to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice library built with a lot reflection tools but i can't release it because of licensing issues (teaser!) [check this out tho](http://code.google.com/p/duckapter/) or this [here](http://code.google.com/p/reflectutils/).  Once you build some basic reflection tools things start to come together pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

See http://innig.net/macker/

Although its not exactly what you want and is more rule based.

Answer (score 0):

I hava used some time ago a nice library called clapper : http://software.clapper.org/javautil/#documentation

In your case - find "classutil" package - it provides simple and useful class discovery and filters, maybe this will be useful.